# Center rsCaption

Tags: css, center, text-alignment

I am currently trying to modify my Royal Slider plugin on Wordpress (http://dimsemenov.com/plugins/royal-slider/)

I am aiming to center the text on all the captions as well as make the caption width 100%

This is the code that is working:

```
<div class="rsContent">
  {{image_tag}}
<div class="rsCaption"> 
    <h3>{{title}}</h3> 
    <p>{{description}}</p>
</div> 
  {{thumbnail}}
  {{html}}
  {{animated_blocks}}
  {{#link_url}}
  <a class="rsLink" href="{{link_url}}">{{title}}</a>
  {{/link_url}}
</div>
```

This is the part I really don't know about:

```
#rsCaption { 
position: absolute;
text-align: center;
```

I am unsure of placement as well.

Any guidance / links would be great. I am a total newbie trying figure this stuff out slowly.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly you have `class="rsCaption"` and your css says `#rsCaption` which is for ids. So your CSS should be something like this:

```
.rsContent { 
    position: relative;
    /* rest of the code that already exists */

}
    .rsContent .rsCaption {
        position: absolute;
        bottom: 0;
        left: 0;
        width: 100%; 
        margin: 0;
    }
```

This is just a wild guess, depends on what you have at the moment. If I would see it somewhere in action that would be something else.

Comment: Thanks for the comments @bebliucGeorge ... here is the link to the slider I am working with http://www.mountainobsession.com/flag-fridays-week-2/

Comment: `Sorry, the page your requested could not be found, or no longer exists.`